# jQuery animation other statement not firing up

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm trying to make a simple animation using Jquery but i'm having a problem.
this is want i'm trying to do: when the page load the 1st image will appear from the top of the page then animate to bottom then after 4seconds & 800 milliseconds it will animate back to the top then disappear. after the 1st image disappear then 2nd image will appear from the top then animate to bottom then after 4seconds & 800 milliseconds it will animate back to the top then disappear. after the 2nd image disappear then 3rd image will appear from the top then animate to bottom then after 4seconds & 800 milliseconds it will animate back to the top then disappear. after the 3rd image disapear it will loopback into the 1st image again..

This is my HTML

```
<div id="DivImgHolderFloat1">
    <img id="ImgFloat1" src="img/banner/Banner-1-float.png">
</div>

<div id="DivImgHolderFloat2">
    <img id="ImgFloat2" src="img/banner/Banner-2-float.png">
</div>

<div id="DivImgHolderFloat3">
    <img id="ImgFloat3" src="img/banner/Banner-3-float.png">
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#DivImgHolderFloat1{
        position: relative;
        width: 350px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 620px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
        #ImgFloat1{
            width: 100%;
        }

    #DivImgHolderFloat2{
        position: relative;
        width: 250px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 400px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
        #ImgFloat2{
            width: 100%;
        }

    #DivImgHolderFloat3{
        position: relative;
        width: 1000px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 230px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
        #ImgFloat3{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

This is my Jquery

```
   var img1 = "none";
var img2 = "up";
var img3 = "up";


if(img2 == "up" && img3 == "up"){
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({"top":"85px"}).animate({"top":"400px"}, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({"opacity":"0.2"}).animate({"opacity":"1"}, "slow");
    img1 ="down";

    function img1GoingUp() {
        if(img1 == "down"){
            $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({"top":"400px"}).animate({"top":"85px"}, "slow");
            $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({"opacity":"1"}).animate({"opacity":"0"}, "slow");
            img1 ="up";
        }
    }
    setInterval(img1GoingUp,4800);  
}

if(img1 == "up" && img3 == "up"){
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({"top":"85px"}).animate({"top":"400px"}, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({"opacity":"0.2"}).animate({"opacity":"1"}, "slow");
    img2 ="down";

    function img2GoingUp() {
        if(img2 == "down"){
            $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({"top":"400px"}).animate({"top":"85px"}, "slow");
            $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({"opacity":"1"}).animate({"opacity":"0"}, "slow");
            img2 ="up";
        }
    }
    setInterval(img2GoingUp,4800);  
}

if(img1 == "up" && img2 == "up"){
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({"top":"85px"}).animate({"top":"400px"}, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({"opacity":"0.2"}).animate({"opacity":"1"}, "slow");
    img3 ="down";

    function img3GoingUp() {
        if(img3 == "down"){
            $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({"top":"400px"}).animate({"top":"85px"}, "slow");
            $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({"opacity":"1"}).animate({"opacity":"0"}, "slow");
            img3 ="up";
        }
    }
    setInterval(img3GoingUp,4800);  
}
```

Comment: it only fires my first if statement where it animate the 1st image.. after the 1st image disappear nothing happen anymore..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting your JavaScript to run more than once; nothing is telling it to do so. When `img1GoingUp` runs and changes those variables, all those `if` statements are not going to re-run.

If you want to run all that if logic multiple times, it ought to be in a function of its own, and at the end of each of your timer events, you'll re-run it:

```
var img1 = "none";
var img2 = "up";
var img3 = "up";

function animate() {
  if(img2 == "up" && img3 == "up") {
    var imgHolder = $("#DivImgHolderFloat1");
    imgHolder.css({"top":"85px"}).animate({"top":"400px"}, "slow");
    imgHolder.css({"opacity":"0.2"}).animate({"opacity":"1"}, "slow");
    img1 ="down";
    function img1GoingUp() {
      if(img1 == "down"){
        imgHolder.css({"top":"400px"}).animate({"top":"85px"}, "slow");
        imgHolder.css({"opacity":"1"}).animate({"opacity":"0"}, "slow");
        img1 ="up";
      }
      animate();
    }
    setInterval(img1GoingUp,4800);  
  }

  // The rest of the logic...
}

// Run the first time
animate();
```

Another problem is you're using `setInterval` when you ought to be using `setTimeout`; `setInterval` will continually repeat every 4800 ms, but since `animate` will run multiple times, you don't want multiple intervals piling up over time.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this approach. I modified your HTML and CSS code to replace `images` with some `div`. Here we need to defined different functions for each step and need to call them one after another via `setTimeout()` and not via `setInterval`. The `setInterval` calls the code infinite time after each interval where as `setTimeout` calls the included code only once after specified time interval.

```js
var img1 = "none";
var img2 = "up";
var img3 = "up";

OnPageLoad();

function OnPageLoad() {
  if (img2 == "up" && img3 == "up") {
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({
      "top": "85px"
    }).animate({
      "top": "400px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({
      "opacity": "0.2"
    }).animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, "slow");
    img1 = "down";

    setTimeout(img1GoingUp, 4800);
  }
}

function img1GoingUp() {
  if (img1 == "down") {
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({
      "top": "400px"
    }).animate({
      "top": "85px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat1").css({
      "opacity": "1"
    }).animate({
      "opacity": "0"
    }, "slow");
    img1 = "up";

    SecondStep();
  }
}

function SecondStep() {
  if (img1 == "up" && img3 == "up") {
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({
      "top": "85px"
    }).animate({
      "top": "400px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({
      "opacity": "0.2"
    }).animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, "slow");
    img2 = "down";

    setTimeout(img2GoingUp, 4800);
  }

}

function img2GoingUp() {
  if (img2 == "down") {
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({
      "top": "400px"
    }).animate({
      "top": "85px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat2").css({
      "opacity": "1"
    }).animate({
      "opacity": "0"
    }, "slow");
    img2 = "up";

    ThirdStep();
  }
}

function ThirdStep() {
  if (img1 == "up" && img2 == "up") {
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({
      "top": "85px"
    }).animate({
      "top": "400px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({
      "opacity": "0.2"
    }).animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, "slow");
    img3 = "down";

    setTimeout(img3GoingUp, 4800);
  }
}

function img3GoingUp() {
  if (img3 == "down") {
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({
      "top": "400px"
    }).animate({
      "top": "85px"
    }, "slow");
    $("#DivImgHolderFloat3").css({
      "opacity": "1"
    }).animate({
      "opacity": "0"
    }, "slow");
    img3 = "up";

    OnPageLoad();
  }
}
```

```css
.circleBase {
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
}
.type1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#DivImgHolderFloat1 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
 
  opacity: 0;
}
#ImgFloat1 {
  width: 100%;
}
#DivImgHolderFloat2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  
  opacity: 0;
}
#ImgFloat2 {
  width: 100%;
}
#DivImgHolderFloat3 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
}
#ImgFloat3 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivImgHolderFloat1">
  <div class="circleBase type1"></div>
</div>

<div id="DivImgHolderFloat2">
  <div class="circleBase type1"></div>
</div>

<div id="DivImgHolderFloat3">
  <div class="circleBase type1"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Please see the running code snippet in full screen mode.